# How to produce a soap web service in spring boot ?

Tags: java, soap, spring-boot

I was following this tutorial of [producing soap web service in spring boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/),

and it left me a little confused. Like where is the wsdl in the first place ? Is this going to generate the wsdl from the countries.xsd ? I didn't get how it is expected to test web service in soapui without having a wsdl file.

Can anyone help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this tutorial they have followed a Bottom-Up approach. If you want to get the WSDL in this example

```
http://<host>:<port>/ws/countries.wsdl
```

To get the country response

```
$ curl --header "content-type: text/xml" -d @request.xml http://localhost:8080/ws
```

Below is the request.xml

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                  xmlns:gs="http://spring.io/guides/gs-producing-web-service">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <gs:getCountryRequest>
         <gs:name>Spain</gs:name>
      </gs:getCountryRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks, I checked it is generating. I feel this should be mentioned there clearly somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the basic 5 steps to produce SOAP web service with Spring Boot.

1. Create an XML schema to define the domain
2. Generate domain classes based on an XML schema
3. Create repository
4. Create service endpoint
5. Configure web service beans

For in detail guide, have look on below blog post and youtube video.

https://prateep.info/2017/12/12/basic-5-steps-to-produce-soap-web-service-with-spring-boot/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SiFSNtDAIS0&t=277s